# How to convert h5 file to GIF within Python

Tags: python-3.x, gif, hdf5, h5py

I'm running a Python simulation script which generates a set of data in h5 file format, and I want to convert it to a gif file.

My current working solution is to use `h5utils`, which I call `h5topng` from outside Python, and it converts my h5 file to a bunch of png files. And then I write another Python script with the `imageio` package to convert the png files to a gif file.

This is quite cumbersome as I have to exist from Python between my 2 Python scripts to call this external command. Ideally I'd like to do everything within Python in one script. Basically `simulation -> data in h5 -> h5 to pngs -> pngs to gif (or h5 -> gif directly)` all within Python. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can use the [Pillow library](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html?highlight=gif) for this.

Comment: You already have a rectangular array of pixel values, right? In PIL, the command is Image.fromarray(your_array, mode). OpenCV has an imwrite() where you can specify the amount of compression you'd like and output to disk a file. There's lots of ways. Otherwise is there something about the question I'm not understanding?

https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imwrite